# Jquery slideDown does not work second time, it fadesin instead.. any ideas?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fadeout, slidetoggle, slidedown

For some reason if you open up the div for the second time it fadesin instead of slidedown which it what is supposed to do, it works fine the first time.. any ideas??

```
//CHECK IF ROW IS VISIABLE
if (!$('#'+rowid).is(':visible')) {
//HIDE ANY OPEN ROWS
$("#tableToggle tr.toggleable").fadeOut('fast', function() { });
//DO SLIDE LOAD FUNCTION


$('#'+rowid).slideDown('slow', function() { });
$("#einfo"+rowid).load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "success") { $("#loader"+rowid).hide(); 
$('#einfo'+rowid).slideDown(200, function() {
$('html, body').delay('200').animate({
scrollTop: $(this).offset().top 
}, 200); }); } });
//HIDE ALL TOGGLEABLE ROWS
}else { $("#tableToggle tr.toggleable").fadeOut('fast', function() { });}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is due to the fact you are never sliding it up but fading it out.   Have you tried to change it to slideUp instead of fadeOut?